# Working in Java NetBeans Maven, JFrame not loading in the buttons or panels I add in the constructor

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

(This is my first question, so apologies if I mess up the format a bit)

When I created the code for the project, the goal was to make a JFrame containing multiple JPanels and JButtons on the sidebar working as a way to switch between them. The JFrame's top level layout manager is a gridbaglayout, with the first column being composed of buttons, and the columns to the right of that making room for the cardlayout containing the JPanels. However, upon running the code, the components are not created.

The constructor is written like this:

```
public HomePage(LobbyList LL, UserList UL, User USER) {
this.cardLayout = new CardLayout();
this.gridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
initComponents();
SetLobbyList(LL);
SetUserList(UL);
SetUser(USER);
CreatePanels();
}
```

The code declaring the various panels needed is written like this:

```
private JoinLobbyPanel JoinPanel; //add functionality by splitting up lobbypage
private NewLobbyPanel CreateLobby; // reference to the lobby creation page
private SearchUserPanel SearchUsers; // reference to the search user page
private JPanel cards; //contains the other functional JPanels
private final CardLayout cardLayout; //layout manager for cards
private final GridBagLayout gridBagLayout; //layout manager for grid
private JPanel grid; //contains the button components and the cards panel
private HomePanel HomePanel;
```

And the code for the actual layout setup is here:

```
private void CreatePanels(){
JoinPanel = new JoinLobbyPanel(ll, ul, user);
CreateLobby = new NewLobbyPanel(ll, ul, user);
SearchUsers = new SearchUserPanel(ul);
// lobbyPage = new LobbyPage(ll, ul, user);
HomePanel = new HomePanel();
cards = new JPanel();
cards.setLayout(cardLayout);
cards.add(JoinPanel, "Join Lobby");
cards.add(CreateLobby, "Create Lobby");
cards.add(SearchUsers, "Search Users");
cards.add(HomePanel, "Home Page");
cardLayout.show(cards, "Home Page");
grid = new JPanel();
grid.setLayout(gridBagLayout);
GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
JButton homeButton = new JButton();
gbc.gridx=0;
gbc.gridy=0;
gbc.weighty=.5;
gbc.gridwidth=1;
gbc.gridheight=1;
homeButton.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) -> {
cardLayout.show(cards, "Home Page");
});
grid.add(homeButton, gbc);
JButton joinButton = new JButton();
gbc.gridx=0;
gbc.gridy=1;
gbc.weighty=.5;
gbc.gridwidth=1;
gbc.gridheight=1;
joinButton.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) -> {
cardLayout.show(cards, "Join Lobby");
});
grid.add(joinButton, gbc);
JButton createButton = new JButton();
gbc.gridx=0;
gbc.gridy=2;
gbc.weighty=.5;
gbc.gridwidth=1;
gbc.gridheight=1;
createButton.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) -> {
cardLayout.show(cards, "Create Lobby");
});
grid.add(createButton, gbc);
JButton searchButton = new JButton();
gbc.gridx=0;
gbc.gridy=3;
gbc.weighty=.5;
gbc.gridwidth=1;
gbc.gridheight=1;
searchButton.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) -> {
cardLayout.show(cards, "Search Users");
});
grid.add(searchButton, gbc);
JButton logOutButton = new JButton();
gbc.gridx=0;
gbc.gridy=4;
gbc.weighty=.5;
gbc.gridwidth=1;
gbc.gridheight=1;
logOutButton.addActionListener((java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) -> {
ul.test();
SignInPage SI = new SignInPage(ul);
SI.setVisible(true);
this.dispose();
});
grid.add(logOutButton, gbc);
gbc.fill=GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
gbc.gridx=1;
gbc.gridy=0;
gbc.weighty=1;
gbc.gridwidth=5;
gbc.gridheight=5;
grid.add(cards, gbc);
this.add(grid);
repaint();
revalidate();
this.pack();
}
```

I tried a few things, including checking to make sure that I used repaint, revalidate, and pack just in case one of those was an issue. I also tried creating a component (a JTextLabel for an experiment) in the constructor, but I noticed that the constructor actually didnt create the JTextLabel either, which suggests to me that somehow the constructor isnt working. I had this problem when I put the test label before and also when I put it after the InitComponents() method. I am not really sure where to begin with debugging this as I am a pretty new programmer and was mostly just trying to reorganize one of my teammates' GUI designs which was dependent on a really inefficient system of creating a new JFrame every time you swapped between pages. I am not getting any runtime or compile time errors, it seems like it would have to be either a logical error on my part or an error with the compiler. Have any of you had a problem like this, and how did you resolve it?

(I am not sure what stackoverflow means by code needs to be indented four spaces so I just made all of my code four spaces away from the side of the textbox. If it meant normal indentation, but just make all the indents four spaces, I apologize and I will fix that)

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.  Use a `CardLayout` and create all of the `JPanels` before you pack and set the `JFrame` visible.

Comment: I am a little bit confused by what you are saying, I used the CardLayout in the code I already have, in this case it is in the CreatePanels() method. Did you mean to drop the GridBagLayout, and add the code for the buttons to each individual panel in their class constructors instead?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the `CardLayout`.  I'd probably create two separate `JPanels` for the `JFrame`, one containing the `CardLayout` and the other for the `JButtons` using a `GridLayout`.  Another option would be to drop the `JButtons` and use a `JTabbedPane` to hold the other `JPanels`.

Comment: No worries, I will consider trying what you suggest with the GridLayout and let you know how it goes

Comment: At what point do you actually add `cards` to the parent container?

Comment: At the very end of the bottom code segment, prior to this.add(grid)

Comment: I edited the code to be a CardLayout and GridLayout and added those separately, but it did not work in the end. Even though they are not nested anymore, the biggest problem is that the panels themselves do not actually show up in the JFrame even though all of the code runs including repaint() revalidate() and this.pack()